# Showing that exterior measure and exterior measure defined using rectangles are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I was working through an exercise in Stein's 3rd Princeton Lectures in Analysis book and was looking for some clarification regarding my approach and its validity.

The problem is precisely showing that for some arbitrary subset E, the normal exterior measure $m_\ast(E)$ is equivalent to $m_\ast^R(E)$, where the latter is defined as $inf \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} |R_{j}|$, where the infinum is taken over all countable closed rectangle covers.

It is of course readily seen that $m_\ast^R(E) \leq m_\ast(E)$, given that all cube coverings are rectangle coverings. As for the reverse inequality, Stein seems fairly suggestive to utilize a lemma in the book that if a rectangle is the finite union of almost disjoint rectangles, its volume is the sum of the constituent rectangles. I anticipate the idea here is to render each closed rectangle as a countable union of closed cubes and thus get a cube covering of the same total volume and so forth, but I had trouble retooling this lemma from the finite to the countable case and furthermore finding a way to represent a closed rectangle as a countable union of closed cubes.

With this is mind, I considered a sort of estimation argument which certainly seems to be not the prettiest, but I am of course most concerned with its validity and only secondarily any notes on how one may attain the result in the way the author clearly intended.

First, we assume for the sake of contradiction that  $m_\ast(E) > m_\ast^R(E)$ (and that the rectangle exterior measure is finite, as contradiction is otherwise straightforward). Then we can find some rectangle covering with volume less than $m_\ast^R(E) + \epsilon$ for arbitrary positive epsilon, say here that epsilon is perhaps $\frac{m_\ast(E) - m_\ast^R(E)}{2}$.

We remark then the corresponding countable covering by closed rectangles, say $\{ \bar R_{j} \}$. For each closed rectangle $\bar R$, we have naturally some open rectangle $R$ both containing $\bar R$ and with $|R| < |\bar R| + \epsilon$ for arbitrary positive epsilon (this is intuitively clear and I won't right down by proof for this result, but it can be established by induction on dimension fairly quickly). Thus, for the family $\{ \bar R_{j} \}$, there is some corresponding collection of open rectangles $\{ R_{j}\}$, such for each $i$ we have $|R_{i}| < |\bar R_{i}| + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n}}$, and this collection is still a cover (this is my main concern, whether or not this reasoning is justified). It follows:
$$
\Big ( \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} |\bar R_{i}| \Big ) + \epsilon = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} |\bar R_{i}| + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}} \geq  \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} |R_{i}|.
$$
But then, as we can represent any open set as a countable union of closed cubes, we have the following where the set $\{ Q_{j}^{i} \}$ represents the cubes that compose the corresponding open rectangle:
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} |R_{i}| = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} |Q_{j}^{i}| = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} |Q_{k}|
$$
Of course then, we now can generate cube coverings with volume sums arbitrarily close to the rectangle exterior measure, generating an easy contradiction. My main qualm lies however in constructing that family of open rectangles and whether or not that is valid. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You argument is perfectly valid as long as your argument of how to construct the open rectangles is valid. Is your concern in that you only got an idea how to construct the open rectangles and not a full proof?

Comment: Admittedly, I have not written the result regarding the open rectangles out, but I do believe that it wouldn't be so hard to establish inductively, as the base case is trivial, and every generalized rectangle of k+1 dimensions is in essence the product of some rectangle in k dimensions with some closed interval, and thus one could limit the volume of the "base" rectangle and choose some extension around the $k+1$th interval that thus contains the whole rectangle and has arbitrarily minimized volume above the whole rectangle's volume.

Comment: My main concern was justifying the construction of the family of rectangles, I was wondering if given this procedure for any particular closed rectangle, one could just remark that there is a countable family of open rectangles such that each rectangle in the family contains its closed counterpart and has volume limited to $\frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$ above the volume of the closed rectangle. I would suppose this stems from my unfamiliarity in working with countable sets like this.

Comment: By the way structured your argument you are invoking the Axiom of choice in some form. You have proven (or convinced yourself) that any rectangle is contained in another open rectangle with the property you want. Now for every element of the countable family $\{R_{j}\}$ you are choosing any such open rectangle $\tilde{R_{j}}$.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with AC don't lose much sleep over this, this is a perfectly reasonable type of argument (assuming AC). If you are familiar with AC I'll still advise don't be overly concerned. AC is necessary for even basic facts in measure theory (countable additivity of the Lebesgue measure for example).

Comment: By properly specifying how to construct the open rectangles you can skip AC in this case. Every $R_{j}$ is of the form $\prod_{i=1}^{n}[a^{j}_{i},b^{i}_{j}]$. Now take $\tilde{R_{j}}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a^{j}_{i}-\delta_{j}(b^{i}_{j}-a^{j}_{i}),b^{i}_{j}+\delta_{j}(b^{i}_{j}-a^{j}_{i}))$ so $|\tilde{R_{j}}|=(1+2\delta_{j})^{n}|R_{j}|$.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough elucidation. I appreciate it! My anxiety does certainly stem for the evocation of AC which I am less familiar with then I would desire. If you wouldn't mind, what specifically about an explicit construction process like the one you gave makes it such that choice is not necessary? What is formally different in giving an explicit construction from proving that there is some such construction for an arbitrary rectangle? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @FZan I've since written out my result for the open rectangles and was wondering if you had any additional comments on my most recent response. Thanks again!

Comment: Let's look at your argument with a little bit more detail: "...Then we can find some rectangle covering with volume less than $m^{R}_{∗}(E)+\varepsilon...$"  here you are choosing a single element from a non-empty set, you assert there must be a covering that satisfies some condition, for that statement to be true (and true it is given your earlier assumption) we would have to show there is a covering satisfying that condition.

Comment: "Thus, for the family $\{R_{j}\}$, there is some corresponding collection of open rectangles $\{ \overline{R}_{j}\}$, such for each i we have $|R_{i}|<|\overline{R}_{i}|+\varepsilon 2n$" Here you are doing something subtly different, we know that for every generic rectangle there is some unspecified open rectangle that contains it and fulfills some other condition, but just as you asked, how do we know there is an entire covering of open rectangles?

Comment: If we were to try to prove this statement following your argument then we would have to do something like this 'for $R_{1}$, $\overline{R_{1}}$ exist (same as you earlier argument), for $R_{2}$, $\overline{R_{2}}$ exists...' our proof would never end! The axiom of choice solves this issue by asserting the existence of a choice function, the covering exists simply because we know there's a choice function $f$ that picks $f(\{  \text{Open rectangles that satisfy the desired condition for $R_{j}$\}} )=\overline{R}_{j}$.

Comment: The other way to solve this issue is by specifying the choice function ourselves, given the fixed covering $\{R_{j}\}$ we give an explicit covering by open rectangles $\{\overline{R}_{j}\}$. That was what the other approach intended to do.

Comment: Awesome, that makes loads of sense, thank you!